# Что делают методы update и digest в библиотеке crypto для node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность, криптография

Есть такой код:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

crypto.createHmac("sha512", this.salt).update(password).digest("hex")
```

Для чего нужны методы update, digest и чем update отличается от второго аргумента метода createHmac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычная реализация хеш-функций в разных библиотеках на разных языках.

Метод `update` нужен для того, что бы можно было считать хеш для сколь угодно большого массива данных, и при этом не нужно его полностью загружать в память. Например, вы хотите посчитать хеш от фильма размером 40 Гб. Для этого вы считываете его небольшими кусками, и закидываете их через метод `update`. В конце вызываете `digest`, и получаете хеш.

Хеш-функции проектируют так, что бы им можно было "скармливать" данные кусками, и при этом эти куски не нужно хранить в памяти. К примеру, SHA512 "кушает" данные блоками по 128 байт, при этом хранит свое состояние всего в 64 байтах (512 битах).

В вашем примере создается хеш-функция HMAC, при этом `salt`, это ее параметр, а не простая конкатенация. Она устроена немного сложнее.

Comment: А если мне, например, нужно еще и без соли хеш получить, то как нужно написать?

Comment: crypto.createHmac("sha512").update(username + password + email).digest("hex")

Comment: или же crypto.createHmac("sha512").update(username).update(password).update(email).digest("hex")

Comment: или crypto.createHmac("sha512", username + password + email).digest("hex")

Comment: Формально это не соль, это пароль или ключ. Под солью подразумевают простую конкатенацию. Если вы хотите так, то используйте просто SHA512 без HMAC: `crypto.createHash('sha512').update(...).digest(...)`

Comment: crypto.createHmac("sha512").update(username + password + email).digest("hex") или crypto.createHmac("sha512").update(username).update(password).update(email).digest("hex")

Comment: Какой лучше 1 или 2 одни и то же по итогу будет?

Comment: Результат должен быть одним и тем же

Comment: Только не `createHmac` а `createHash`, как я написал в комменте своем

Comment: А какая между ними разница?

Comment: HMAC это хеш-функция с 2 параметрами: другая хеш-функция и ключ. А `createHash` создает "чистую" хеш-функцию.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за ответ